# Compiling OpenCV Based Script With G++

Tags: c++, macos, opencv, clang++

I want to begin writing saying that I know that this topic has been talked about multiple times. I can see several posts with similar titles as I'm typing this now. The reason that I'm asking this question once again is because I've tried what those posts stay, and it still won't work. I've copied a simple script that upscales an image using opencv in C++ to begin the learning journey and to make a script that I hope to use in the future very often, maybe even share on GitHub. With that being said, here's more detail about my issue.

In my IDE, Visual Studio Code, my include path has been set to "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/opencv/4.6.0/include/opencv4/".

I've tried using the -I arguments, -l arguments, whatever this is: "`pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`", but none of that worked.

The only time that I could get it to work is using the following command, but even then, g++ returned: `fatal error: too many errors emitted, stopping now [-ferror-limit=] 41 warnings and 20 errors generated.`

Here's the program that I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

int main() {
    Mat frame = imread("/Users/karsoneskind/Desktop/Programming/C++/ibootimformer/tests/image.jpg");
    namedWindow("Output", 0);

    namedWindow("Input", 0);

    Mat output;

    resize(frame, output, Size(1000, 200), 0, 0);

    imshow("Output", output);
    imshow("Input", frame);

    waitKey(0);
}
```

**Edit: This is the command in terminal I used to try to compile the code:**

> g++ test.cpp -o test pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4

Comment: Are you trying to compile inside VSCode or are you building from the shell? If you are building from VSCode can you add the `tasks.json` edited? Or are you using some other build extension like CMakeTools or MakeFileTools? If so we would need to see the files related to those.

Comment: @drescherjm No. I am doing it directly from terminal. All I did was CD into the directory the .cpp file was in, than ran this command: g++ test.cpp -o test `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv4`

Comment: actually, just libopencv4 is not enough. You must secify all of OpenCV libs you used, i.e libopencv_core, libopencv_imgproc, libopencv_highgui...

Comment: Didn't work. Same thing as before: It says that one of the header files isn't found, and it also says that none of the libraries exist. This is the command I used: g++ test.cpp -o tets `pkg-config --cflags --libs libopencv_core, libopencv_imgproc, libopencv_highgui`

Comment: Your post mentions that you are on a Mac. The normal compiler to use on a Mac is clang which is shipped with Xcode. I tried on Linux with your code and both the commands: `g++ cv.cpp $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs)` and  `clangg++ cv.cpp $(pkg-config opencv4 --cflags --libs)` did work from the first try, with the code you put inside cv.cpp.

Comment: @Jean-MichaëlCelerier neither of those commands worked for me. I still got the error that opencv2/opencv.hpp file was not found.